# Kivy: How to change ScreenManager's "current" property on __init__

Tags: python, kivy

My App is a ScreenManager. Depending on the circumstances, I want the active screen to either be "Screen 1" or "Screen 2" when the app opens. How would I do this the most elegant way? I thought that this is as trivial as changing the `current` property in the initialization of the app. Sadly, this does not work. Here's what should work imo:

main.py:

```
MyApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return Builder.load_file("MyApp.kv")

     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         if foo: # Here's the problem:
             self.root.current = "Screen 1"
         else:
             self.root.current = "Screen 2"
```

MyApp.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
        name: "Screen 1"
    Screen2:
        name: "Screen 2"

<Screen1@Screen>
etc...
```

But it doesn't. Throws the following error:

```
    self.root.current = "Screen 1"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'
```

My guess is that I set the `current` attribute to early, before `root` is set. An idea of mine is to 1) create a property-var for MyApp, 2) set `current` to be that property, 3) change that property in the init method. That's a lot of effort and code-cluttering just to change a screen on initialization.

How would I do it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's simply because you don't have `self.root` object specified. Why would you need to change Screens during `__init__` ? You should use `build` function for that.

My example:

```
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    Screen:
        name: "Screen 1"
        Label:
            text: "Screen 1!"

    Screen:
        name:"Screen 2"
        Label:
            text: "Screen 2!"
''')

class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Root()

        foo = random.randint(0,1)
        if foo:
            self.root.current = "Screen 1"
        else:
            self.root.current = "Screen 2"

        return self.root



MyApp().run()
```

`self.root.cureent_screen` property will be changed before `self.root` object will be visible

Comment: But that's one additional, imo cumbersome step just to be able to change `root`. I fixed the problem by scheduling the change of screens one frame further, like this `Clock.schedule_once(self.set_current_screen)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Only this is working.**

*I said such statement as of I tryed many codes(but not works)*

```
class NextScreen(ScreenManager):


    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(NextScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #code goes here and add:
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.Android_back_click)

    def Android_back_click(self,window,key,*largs):
        # print(key)
        if key == 27:

            if self.current_screen.name == "Screen1" or self.current_screen.name == "Screen_main":
                return False

            elif self.current_screen.name == "Screen2":
                try:
                    self.current = "Screen1"
                except:
                    self.current = "Screen_main"
          
            return True
```

**Use 'esc' button to get key(27) which means back in android**

Comment: ***and don't forget to import Window                 ***    from kivy.core.window import Window